# How to play songs using XML in my Android application?

Tags: java, android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- generator="FeedCreator 1.7.2"-->
<rss version="2.0">
  <strings>
    <level>one</level>
  </strings>
  <item>
    <contentitem>
      <title>Song 1</title>
      <view>Song 1</view>
      <english>Song1.mp3</english>
    </contentitem>
  </item>
  <item>
    <contentitem>
      <title>Song 2</title>
      <view>Song 2</view>
      <english>song2.mp3</english>
    </contentitem>
  </item>
  <item>
    <contentitem>
      <title>Song 3</title>
      <view>Song 3</view>
      <english>song3.png</english>
      <spanish>song3.png</spanish>
    </contentitem>
  </item>
  <item>
    <contentitem>
      <title>Song 4</title>
      <view>Song 4</view>
      <english>song4.mp3</english>
      <spanish>song4.mp3</spanish>
    </contentitem>
  </item>
</rss>
```

Above is mine XML file I just want to play music using this XML file suppose I am visiting the 0th block App play song1.mp3 if I am visiting the 1st block App play song2.mp3 and so on... I wort the function like this....

```
android.view.View.OnClickListener spanish = new android.view.View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        MediaPlayer m = MediaPlayer.create(Formulae.this, R.drawable.song1.mp3);
        m.start();
    }
};
```

Above code is static how can I make it dynamic (R.drawable.song1.mp3) according to selected block...and things comes form the XML. Please help me out Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

just to give you the idea

```
android.view.View.OnClickListener spanish = new android.view.View.OnClickListener() {
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // we want to create the mediaPlayer Instance
        // just once
        if(mediaPlayer==null)
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        // try getting the new Title that should be played
        String pathToNewTitle = getPathFromClickedViewItem(v);
        // stop current Song
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e1) {
            // implement this yourself
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            // implement this yourself
        }
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    private String getPathFromClickedViewItem(View v)  {
        String path;

        // you have to implement this yourself
        // the idea is to determine the path 
        // for the mp3 that should be played
        // when a specific view item is clicked

        return path;
    }
};
```

playing audio video on android -> http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html

reading a xml file on android -> http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xml/sax/package-summary.html

since you know your i'd suggest using xpath -> http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html

if you don't know how to put this togehter, you should first learn oo-programming and java!